# How to make custom fields respect paragraph breaks

Tags: custom-field

In one part of my site I am displaying custom field data like this:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'info', true);
?>
```

This works ok but it strips any paragraph breaks out and displays it all as one big block which makes it hard to read.

So how do I make it respect the paragraph breaks?

many thanks in advance!

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this obviously depends on the content of your 'info' custom field;
generally, you could try:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($postid, 'info', true));
```